Integration Problem with Proof that 4 Random Variables are Independent Given Their Joint pdf
I have a problem where I need to show that 4 random variables are independent given their joint pdf. I just want to make sure I have the right approach:

$W, X, Y \text{and } Z$ are continuous random variables with joint pdf
$$ f_{W,X,Y,Z}(w,x,y,z)=3e^{-27w}(x+1)(y+1)^2e^{-y}wz\cos(\pi z/4)$$
for $0\leq w,x,y,z \leq 2$. Prove that $W, X, Y \text{and } Z$ are independent

My initial thought is to find $f_W(w), f_X(x), f_Y(y) \text{and } f_Z(z)$ and show that
$$f_W(w)\cdot f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)\cdot f_Z(z)=f_{W,X,Y,Z}(w,x,y,z)$$
Would this be sufficient? 
Also, to find each marginal pdf do I just take the triple integral of the joint pdf w.r.t the other random variables? 
For instance
$$f_W(w)=\int_0^2\int_0^2\int_0^23e^{-27w}(x+1)(y+1)^2e^{-y}wz\cos(\pi z/4)dxdydz=
3we^{-27w}(4)(5-17e^{-2})(\frac{8\pi-16}{\pi^2})$$
$$f_X(x)=\int_0^2\int_0^2\int_0^23e^{-27w}(x+1)(y+1)^2e^{-y}wz\cos(\pi z/4)dwdydz=
(\frac{e^{-54}(e^{54}-55)}{729})(x+1)(5-17e^{-2})(\frac{8\pi-16}{\pi^2})$$
$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^2\int_0^2\int_0^23e^{-27w}(x+1)(y+1)^2e^{-y}wz\cos(\pi z/4)dwdxdz=
(\frac{e^{-54}(e^{54}-55)}{729})(4)(y+1)^2e^{-y}(\frac{8\pi-16}{\pi^2})$$
$$f_Z(z)=\int_0^2\int_0^2\int_0^23e^{-27w}(x+1)(y+1)^2e^{-y}wz\cos(\pi z/4)dwdxdy=
(\frac{e^{-54}(e^{54}-55)}{729})(4)(5-17e^{-2})z\cos(\pi z/4)$$
Because I tried this approach and I failed to get an answer that proved the result. Did I just make mistake in my integration?
Thank you

In order to prove independency it is enough to show that the joint probability can be written as a product  $f_1(w)f_2(x)f_3(y)f_4(z)$. You do not need to find the marginals. If you still want to then find constants $c_i$ such that the functions $c_if_i(\cdot)$ are pdf's.

Oh ok, that makes the problem a lot simpler. Thank you @drhab !
